# mongoDB spring-boot custom query in uppercase, with LIKE

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, nosql

I need to search the items by their names via spring boot on a db implemented by **mongodb**. For a normal **SQL** database I would've done as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER(CONCAT('%', :name, '%'))")
List<Customer> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

Yet it does not accept a normal 'SELECT' query, because it is a **NoSQL** database. Thus I need to query this collection by using **JSON** format, yet I have no idea of the implementation on spring-boot.. This is my first time using **mongodb** too.

Going through the posts on stackoverflow, I have found an example such as:

`@Query("{'name':?0}")`

And on [this site](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) there are examples. Also [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) there is an explanation of the query above. Yet still I have no idea how to convert the former query I have pasted above into a "json based query".

**Note**: I am extending MongoRepository on my repository.

**Note2**: The above query is case sensitive, that's the reason I am trying to query in upper case along with converting the column data into upper case.

**UPDATE**

```
@Query(" { $text: { $search: ?0 , $caseSensitive: false } }")
```

works perfectly(I had to index my collection by launching this command:`db.customerCollection.createIndex({name: "text"})` ) to ignore case sensitivity, but I still need to implement '**LIKE**'; because when I search 'user', it is able to find 'UsEr' etc. But if I search 'se', it doesn't bring me any result. Any help will be appreciated!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you tried this query { $text: { $search: ?0 , $caseSensitive: true } }  . You can check this for reference. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It gives me an error saying: "text index required for $text query". Now I am searching a way to resolve it.

Comment: I have added the indexes to my collection and it works all right! The only remaining thing is to implement LIKE now.. When I search 'red' it finds 'Red' but if I search only a part of it, it is not able to find the object. I will update my question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by using `$regex` and writing the query as:

```
@Query(" { companyName: { $regex : '(?i)?0'}  } }")
```

I would've never guessed to spend that much time for such a simple thing. But I am glad that it is resolved anyway !

[[ref]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex)